# Data back NULL in OPC UA client with VB.net

Tags: opc-ua, opcode

im trying to connect to a S7 1500 PLC with an OPC UA client with the Visual Studio using VB.net.
The project need to be auto, so i have an Excel that have the names of the variables that i will read with the OPC connection.
The problem is that when i try to read a single node it works and give me back the value correctly, but when i tried to do it with an array to save the data (for later introduccing it in an SQL Server) i gave me back the value NULL, i have tried to convert using CType or other but it still fails.
here Is the code:
The variable Arr_Celdas contanins the names of the vars for the string. The var Rwcnt is a function that reads the number of rows in the Excel(number of variables). And the Var Filas is for the Fors

```
        Dim Client_OPC As New OpcClient("opc.tcp://10.1.0.128:4840")    'Conexión             

        Dim Lectura_OPC(Fila) As String     'Array con los nombres de las variables para la lectura de valores OPC
        Dim Valor_Nodo_OPC(Rwcnt) As OpcValue   'Variable con el valor del nodo OPC

        Client_OPC.Connect()    'Conexión al servidor

        If Err.Number = 0 Then      'Rutina de espera antes del siguiente paso y rutina de error
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente OPC conectado")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Else
            Dim ErrorDesc As String = Err.Description & "(" & Err.Number & ")"
            Console.WriteLine(ErrorDesc)
            Client_OPC.Disconnect()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        
        Dim Lectura_OPC_1 As String = """ns = 3;s=""Registros_procesados"".""Registros_ATV_Izda""."""
        Dim Lectura_OPC_2(Fila) As String
        For Fila = 1 To Rwcnt
            Lectura_OPC_2(Fila) = Arr_Celdas(Fila) + """"
            Lectura_OPC(Fila) = Lectura_OPC_1 + Lectura_OPC_2(Fila) + """"
        Next
        'Console.WriteLine(Lectura_OPC(11))


        Do While (True)     'Bucle cada 100 ms

           

            'Dim Prueba As OpcValue = Client_OPC.ReadNode("ns=3;s=""Registros_procesados"".""Registros_ATV_Izda"".""Encoder frequency""")    'Valor encoder y lectura del nodo correspondiente

            For Fila = 1 To Rwcnt
                Valor_Nodo_OPC(Fila) = CType(Client_OPC.ReadNode(Lectura_OPC(Fila)), OpcValue)
            Next

            If Err.Number = 0 Then      'Rutina de espera antes del siguiente paso y rutina de error
                Console.WriteLine("Obteniendo valores")
                'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Else
                Dim ErrorDesc As String = Err.Description & "(" & Err.Number & ")"
                Console.WriteLine(ErrorDesc)
                Client_OPC.Disconnect()
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Console.WriteLine(Valor_Nodo_OPC(11))
```

THANKS AND HOPE U CAN HELP ME :)

Comment: Hello, which OPC UA client library are you using?

Comment: Im using Opc.UaFx.Client.